# Tomcat 7 logging separation by host name

Tags: logging, tomcat7, virtualhost

I use a Tomcat 7 installation as web container for multiple virtual hosts. Each web app has its own set of log files that I separate by hostname, e.g. /logs/www.somehost.com/logfile.log and /logs/www.anotherhost.com/logfile.log.

I would like to separate the logging from Tomcat itself (e.g. catalina.*, tomcat7-stderr.*, and tomcat7-stdout.*) by host name also, but I cannot see how to do this in Tomcat 7. The [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default)) for Tomcat 8.5 refers to a property replacement `${classloader.hostName}`, but this does not seem to work in Tomcat 7.

Is it possible to dynamically set the folder name for Tomcat 7 logging through base `logging.properties` file? Can I reference the `Host name` as defined in `server.xml` for property replacement in a context-deployed `logging.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. I found out that setting `${classloader.hostName}` only has an effect when set in `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` within the `war` file. Setting it in `logging.properties` in the `conf` folder of Tomcat didn't have any effect.